# Pass parameter to all views

Tags: controller, symfony, parameter-passing, twig

I want to display the username/last connection date/time and some other info on all of my Twig views (which all extend from a common Twig layout).

How can I achieve that without having to explicitly pass those parameters from each controller to each view?

Do I have to create a Twig extension, or make a call to a controller/action that will retrieve username/connection/other info from the layout using **render**?

I'd like a simpler solution if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User is accessible as a predefined global variable, take a look at [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#global-template-variables), and if you want to reuse the same template fragment in all your templates take a look at the [include](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html#include) tag.

Comment: I'm actually using the session (app.session.get('myuser').myProperty ) from twig to get the info I need, as I'm storing more info than what's available in the user variable.

Answer (score 10):

The simplest solution is to [embed controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers) from your templates/layout. But beware that subrequests are costly and can affect performance significantly. If at some point you'll notice that the dev version of your app is slow as hell, then know that the reason is probably several subrequests on each request.

The next solution is [Twig extensions](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html). In most cases you'll want [functions](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions). You could call it like:

```
{{ user_info(user) }}
```

I started with embedding controllers first, but my dev version reached the point when most pages on my site were timing out in 30 seconds. I didn't know the reason first, but as soon as I found it out, I replaced all subrequsts with Twig extensions. Since then the performance is back to normal.

Comment: Did you ever tried to render a controller without teig templates, i.e. in a pure PHP class? Do this solution affects the performance too?

Comment: @JeanValjean, the reason is in subrequests themselves — not in Twig.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it was available when this question was posted in 2012, but I'd use Twig Globals.

From http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#globals :

> ### Globals
>
> A global variable is like any other template variable, except that
>   it's available in all templates and macros:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addGlobal('text', new Text());
```

> You can then use the text variable anywhere in a template:
>
> ```
> {{ text.lipsum(40) }}
> ```

I put the code in some place where it will get called each time, like the controller constructor or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Had this use-case just last month. Turned to `render` command and it really worked great as called controller action does not have to have `@Route` defined... not even a `@Template` but that's up to you ;)