# symfony2: how to access service from template

Tags: php, symfony

If I created a service is there a way to access it from twig, without creating a twig.extension?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can set the service a twig global variable in `config.yml`, e.g

```
#app/config/config.yml
twig:
    globals:
        your_service: "@your_service"
```

And in your `template.html.twig` file you can invoke your service this way:

```
{{ your_service.someMethod(twig_variable) }}
```

See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/twig.html).

Comment: or just get the whole container by doing "@service_container"

Comment: @Gigala Only inject what you really need, much cleaner.

Comment: just saying, some may want the whole thing

Comment: I may prefer to insert the service in the controllerAction instead as a global variable o.O

Comment: in my service i have some arguments like @request so i have this error :

The definition "twig" references the service "my_service" which belongs to a narrower scope. 

How can i do ?

Comment: Seconding the comment by @altore. My service needs to be scoped to `request` so when I try to define it as a global twig variable as above I get a `ScopeWideningInjectionException` Exception...any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

To get this done in Symfony 5, first you must declare the service in services.yaml, for example:

```
        App\Service\NavigationHelper:
        arguments:
            foo: bar
```

Then you can declare the service for its use in Twig. To achieve this, you must add it as a variable in the "globals" section of the Yaml file located in packages/twig.yaml:

```
  globals:
    navHelper: '@App\Service\NavigationHelper'
```

Now you can use your service methods from the templates as Mun Mun Das suggested in his last code snippet.