# Call services in templates

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig

Following [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244717/avoid-repeating-the-same-query-in-controllers-for-parent-template) I can't manage to call the service from the template. I did exactly like in the answer, but I get 'Variable "newmessages" does not exist' in the template.

I also tried returning the service in the parent template, but the parent is never called since there is no request to it, the requests are done only to child templates.

```
public function indexAction(){
    $locationService = $this->container->get('newmessages');


    return $this->render(
        'MedAppCrudBundle:UserBackend\Message:index.html.twig',
        array('newmessages'=>$locationService->methodToCalculate())

    );
}
```

How to call service from parent template? The answer from last question doesn't work.

Comment: Expose it as a twig extension

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, please?

Comment: hi @George check my answer

Comment: You editing wrong template if you see that error. You can only access this variable in `MedAppCrudBundle:UserBackend\Message:index.html.twig` but you can pass it to other template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is quite simple. You expose the service as a twig global variable. Based on your example, you should add something similar to your `config.yml`

```
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    globals:
        newmessages: "@newmessages"
```

To use it in your twig, you would just write `{{ newmessages.methodToCalculate() }}`.

You can read more about this in the [How to Inject Variables into all Templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html#referencing-services)  documentation page.

Here is a more detailed example:

```
// Add this to config.yml
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    globals:
        newmessages: "@newmessages"
```

---

```
// Add this to services.yml (or if you're using older version of Symfony, add it to config.yml as well)
services:
    newmessages:
        class: App\YourBundle\Service\NewMessages
```

---

```
// The NewMessages service class
<?php

namespace App\YourBundle\Service;

class NewMessages {

    public function methodToCalculate() {
        return "location calculated.";
    }

}

?>
```

---

```
 // in your twig template do this
 {{ newmessages.methodToCalculate() }}  // outputs "location calculated."
```

Comment: Hm, is there no problem if it is globally declared? I want to use it only in a few templates and being able to use it in all of them seems bad to me.

Comment: If you're not using [Lazy service injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/lazy_services.html) your service is already loaded either way so it's pretty much the same thing. if you use `Lazy Services` then it would only be instantiated when you actually call a method from your service.

Comment: I'm getting 'Attempted to load class "NewMessagesService" from namespace "MedApp\CrudBundle\MedAppCrudBundle\Services".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?'

Comment: You're probably doing something wrong. I've updated my answer with an oversimplified example of how it should be.

Answer (score 1):

You can expose your service as a twig function and use it in the twig statement. [See the full doc here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html).
 As example, define an extension as:

services.yml

```
#########  TWIG EXTENSION
    acme.message_helper_twig_extension:
        class: Acme\MessageBundle\Twig\MessageHelperExtension
        arguments: [@newmessages]
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

And implement it as follow:

```
namespace Acme\MessageBundle\Twig\MessageHelperExtension;



class MessageHelperExtension extends \Twig_Extension {


    protected $newMessages;


    function __construct($newMessages)
    {
        $this->newMessages = $newMessages;
    }



    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            //////////////////////////////////
            'twig_method_reference_name'=> new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'getMessages'),
        );
    }

    public function getMessages()
    {
        return $this->newMessages->getMessages()
    }
    /**
     * Returns the name of the extension.
     *
     * @return string The extension name
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'message_helper';
    }

}
```

Then you can use it in the twig as:

```
{{ twig_method_reference_name() }}
```

Hope this help

Comment: So everytime I have a parent twig with a variable I have to define a service and then define it as twig extension? Sounds like a lot of pointless work and it seems like simply calling it in every controller would be a better solution. Or am I wrong?

Comment: a twig extension is only a manner for expose a service to the twig layer. The `newmessages` is suppose is a service that return, in the method exposed, the number of new messages to the twig. Hope this clarify my intent

Comment: Although this is a technically valid answer, I believe it adds a bit more complexity to the equation - one more service, one more class (which is a wrapper around the original). IMHO, twig extensions are mainly used to further extend core twig functionality like additional functions and filters.