# How to make message notification in symfony?? exampe message[1]

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3, symfony3.x, symfony-3.4

Someone told me to use flag, but I'm using in base template(where I have menus) to display the message notification which was unable to do.

```
class countMail extends Controller{

    public function indexAction(){
        $count_em = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:St_Jude_Email');
        $count_dql = $count_em->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->select('count(c.flag)')
                ->where('c.flag = 0');
        $flag_count = $count_dql->getQuery();
        $count = $flag_count->getSingleScalarResult();

        return $this->render('admin/countMail.html.twig', [
                    'count' => $count
        ]);
    }

}
```

In twig

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}
{% block count %}

    {{ count }}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Why should we lose time trying to understand your code if you don't take time to format ..

Comment: You should have a look at flash messages: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-improved-flash-messages

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing. But I think the following steps will help you.

1. You need to write a service that will output the number of emails.
   Refer https://symfony.com/doc/3.0/service_container.html or https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html for write a service.
2. Then you need to call this service from the twig, and you will get what you need. 
   Check [symfony2: how to access service from template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243638/symfony2-how-to-access-service-from-template?answertab=votes#tab-top) for it.

Comment: I mean the message notification like in Facebook message etc