# CPU issues when loading pages with Symfony 2

Tags: performance, symfony, cpu

I'm posting here because I am experiencing a pretty boring issue on my Symfony2 project. (v.2.1.5)
Since a few days, my whole website is becoming very slow, and every pages (including the simplest) take something like 4 or 5 second to load.

Obviously, I tried my project on differents servers, with Windows (WAMP and XAMPP server) and a Debian server (with PHP 5.3.9).

On all these servers, I had the same problem : Pages are very slow, and the CPU is over-used while loading. I checked the CPU with the dev-mode, without, and after cleaning the cache. Every time, the CPU looks to much used for these tasks.

I also took some screenshots to explain my problem.

---

Symfony2 profiler : http://intuitiv.nanakii.fr/upload/profiler.jpg

CPU usage :

On dev mode after cleaning the cache : http://intuitiv.nanakii.fr/upload/318-dev-nocache.PNG

On dev mode with the cache : http://intuitiv.nanakii.fr/upload/318-dev-cache.PNG

Without dev mode, after cleaning the cache : http://intuitiv.nanakii.fr/upload/318-prod-nocache.PNG

Without dev mode, with the cache : http://intuitiv.nanakii.fr/upload/318-prod-cache.PNG

---

All the CPU screenshots show the CPU usage on my system, while loading one page on the website.

I know my issue is not very accurate, and I understand that it won't be easy to help me with these information.

But, I really don't know where investigate to fix that problem. So, every ideas will be useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Compared to my profiler, everything is long, especially the request (loading + firewall)

Do you use Twig's render tag a lot ? It is known to [slow down everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862585/symfony2-and-twig-render-performance-issues).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but no, we don't use the render tag.. But thanks for the information ;)